# How do I save finance calculations results for a transaction in a Django Model's fields

Tags: django, django-models

## Description

I am making a small Shop manager app in **Django** for my portfolio, I have in total 4 models in my project, one of them being a **"Transaction" model**, I would like to know **how can I save** the profit, income and costs of the related products for the related order to this Model?

### Other details

I'm using Django 4.2.3 and temporarily an SQLite Database.

You can find it's GitHub repo here: https://github.com/Technopy311/ShopFinaceManager-Django

Any help and/or collaboration is greatly appreciated and proper credits will be given in the project.

### My attempt of fix this issue

I tried to overwrite the Model's save method (Transaction Model) as indicated at the Django's documentation, and in there call the created methods (calc_cost, calc_income and calc_profit) before saving the instance itself, but it did not work.

Here are the relevant models (Transaction, Order and Product).
My code is divided in **2 apps, Core and Finance**.

### Transaction

```py
from django.db import models
from core.models import Order


class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField("Transaction's date", auto_now=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)        

    total_profit = models.IntegerField("Transaction's Profit", default=0)
    total_cost = models.IntegerField("Transaction's Income", default=0)
    total_income = models.IntegerField("Transaction's Income", default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Transaction #{self.pk}"


    # Here is the issue, I do not know how to save this calculations

    def calc_cost(self):
    
        for product in self.order.product.objects.all():
            self.total_cost += product.price_cost()


    def calc_income(self):
        for product in self.order.product.objects.all():
            self.total_income += product.price_sell()


    def calc_profit(self):
        self.total_profit = self.total_income - self.total_cost
```

### Product and Order

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Product Name", default="Product", max_length=200)
    price_sell = models.IntegerField("Product sell Price", default=0)
    price_cost = models.IntegerField("Product cost Price", default=0)
    stock = models.IntegerField("Product Stock", default=0)
    description = models.TextField("Product Description", default="", max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField("Product Image", default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Order(models.Model):
    ordered_by = models.CharField("Person who ordered", max_length=100, default="---")
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField("Created datetime", auto_now_add=True)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField("Updated datetime", auto_now=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField("Order Status", default=False)


    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product}"
```

Comment: Can you provide your transaction.save() method also?

Answer (score 0):

try this in Transaction model, with only one query you will have all data you need:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     order.product.objects.aggregate(product_cost=Sum('price_cost'),
                                    product_sell=Sum('price_sell'))
     self.total_cost = product_cost
     self.total_income = product_sell

     self.total_profit = self.total_income - self.total_cost

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Afj your idea is what I needed. I had to fix some details in my models and change a little bit your solution, but (again) your help has saved my project.

Here is the final code that I implemented.

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.order.product_set.aggregate(
            Sum('price_cost',),
            Sum('price_sell')
        )


        self.total_cost = data['price_cost__sum']
        self.total_income = data['price_sell__sum']

        self.total_profit = self.total_income - self.total_cost

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note: I had to change my model relationships, hence the *product__set* change.

I will give you the proper credits as promised in the Githb Repo.
Again, thank you so much! Without your help I couldn't have made it